# Float Right Elements Are Rendered Higher than other elements

Tags: html, css

I have this issue where my `float: right` element is indeed floated right but it's above other elements and sometimes it even goes offscreen

My CSS:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
header {
    background-color: black;
}
#header-limiter * {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
}
header span {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;

}
#header-limiter {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
     display: block;
}
#logoText {
    font-size: 16px;
}
#logout-btn {
    float: right;
}
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wLftd9ph/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logout text doesn't have the same default margin as the `p` text (`logoText`).

Simply add `margin: 1em 0` to `#logout-btn`.

http://jsfiddle.net/wLftd9ph/5/

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to fix alignment would be to use `display: inline-block` with `vertical-align: middle` instead of floats as you can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/exmubg5m/

```
#logout-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to logo text.

```
float: left;
z-index: 0;
```

Also remove the `<p>` tag from the Logo 'text' as this adds a new paragraph.

```
<span>LogoText</span>
```